# Laravel not sending Pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher

So I am setting up pusher with Laravel and I can't get it to send messages. They are not received in the pusher debug console, so the error must be while sending them. Here is any information you might need to help me spot the error, as I spent hours trying to fix it and can't get any further now.

Relevant information from my .env file:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

PUSHER_APP_ID=iscorrect
PUSHER_APP_KEY=iscorrect
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=iscorrect
```

My broadcasting.php

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'eu',
            'encrypted'=>true
        ],
    ],
```

The event that should fire the message

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class HelloPusherEvent implements ShouldBroadcast 
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Only (!) Public members will be serialized to JSON and sent to Pusher
**/
public $message;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['my-channel'];
}
}
```

And finally my route that should trigger the event:

```
Route::get('/pusher', function() {
event(new App\Events\HelloPusherEvent('Hi there Pusher!'));
return "Event has been sent!";
});
```

I don't get any errors when visiting /pusher, but my Pusher Debug console is "waiting for events" unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the built in p[usher client logging system](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/getting-started/server-debugging.html)

Comment: When I follow the mentioned steps, I get 

ReflectionException (-1)
"Class pusher does not exist"

upon opening any page of my website.

Comment: This also happens, when I now to composer update. It gives me the same ReflectionException. However, when I reverser the changes, everything works out again, considering calling the page or updating composer. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Check your local apache / nginx logs for a message saying "unable to get local isuer certificate".

If so, define path of curl.cainfo in your PHP config.

The file can be downloaded [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)